# How to wait for Function to finish before continuing

Tags: ios, swift

In my current project I want to be able to display the users current position on a map. 
I have implemented this functionality via the `requestLocation` method provided by Apple, but the problem is that my code continues without waiting for the `requestLocation` Function to finish.

The flow is this: First I call the `positionController.setPositionViaLocationData()` function, which handles the setup and execution of the `requestLocation` method. In the end this receives the coordinates and stores them in the `userPosition` member of the `PositionController`. 
In the next line of code I want to access the `userPosition` via the `PositionController` but here comes my problem:

The line ...

```
var userPosition = positionController.getPosition()
```

... is executed *before* `positionController.setPositionViaLocationData()` is finished, thus it takes the default values stored in `userPosition`.

How can I make my code wait for `positionController.setPositionViaLocationData()` before executing
`var userPosition = positionController.getPosition()`?
I already read stuff about Closures and CompletionManagers but I don't get that stuff to work for me.

Heres the code of both classes, first the ViewController who calls the functions:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let positionController = PositionController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        positionController.setPositionViaLocationData()
        var userPosition = positionController.getPosition()
        setUserPositionMarkerOnMapAndShowMap(userPositionLatitude: userPosition.userLatitude, userPositionLongitude: userPosition.userLongitude)

    }

    func setUserPositionMarkerOnMapAndShowMap(userPositionLatitude: Double, userPositionLongitude: Double){
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userPositionLatitude,
                                              longitude: userPositionLongitude, zoom:3)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera:camera)
        let marker = GMSMarker()

        self.view = mapView
        marker.snippet = "Munich"
        marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
        marker.map = mapView

        self.view = mapView
    }

}
```

And now my `PositionController` class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class PositionController: CLLocationManager, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager: CLLocationManager
    var userPosition = Position(longitude: 0,latitude: 0)

    override init() {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        print("---------------Init---------------------------")
    }

    func setPositionViaLocationData(){

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

    func setPosition(longitude: Double, latitude: Double){
        userPosition.longitude = longitude
        userPosition.latitude = latitude
    }

    func getPosition() -> (userLongitude: Double, userLatitude: Double){
        return (userPosition.longitude, userPosition.latitude)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        userPosition.latitude = locValue.latitude
        userPosition.longitude = locValue.longitude
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ,May I know why are you not able to execute this task Via closure?

Comment: Well, I might work via closure its just that I was unable to get it to work. Its highly likely that I just didn't do it correct ,even though I tried for a long time, since I am new to Swift.

Comment: The [CLLocationManager documentation] (https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation) indicates that the requestLocation() method returns immediately and that the method signature doesn't support closures. The method that is called when the location information is available is [locationManager didUpdateLocations](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager) and here is where one gets the updated location.

Comment: The `requestUserLocation()` method returns immediately. You need to use its delegates to control your flow. From the `didUpdateLocations` or `didFailWithError` you can call your next function.

Comment: @regicide Please also note that the PositionController has two CLLocationManager classes: PositionController class extends CLLocationManager but also declares the member locationManager of type CLLocationManager which is redundant.

Comment: Jack is right (though this is admittedly unrelated to your question). It should be `class PositionController: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate { ... }` or just `class PositionController: NSObject { ... }` and then implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods in extension, e.g. `extension PositionController: CLLocationManagerDelegate { ... }`.

Comment: The answer to "how do I wait" is "don't". Instead present some UI that indicates that something is going on (e.g. a spinning `UIActivityIndicatorView`, perhaps something that dims or blurs the map underneath it, etc), the start the asynchronous `PositionController` process, and then provide a mechanism for the `PositionController` to tell the view controller to remove that spinner when the asynchronous process is done (perhaps using delegate-protocol pattern that [Juan shared with you below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44373757/1271826)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delegate to notify MapViewController that the user position has been updated.

You can add the next protocol above the PositionController class definition

```
protocol PositionControllerDelegate: class {
  func didUpdatePosition(_ newPosition: Position)
}
```

Then add a new optional property to PositionController

`weak var delegate: PositionControllerDelegate?`

And then call the delegate method:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    userPosition.latitude = locValue.latitude
    userPosition.longitude = locValue.longitude
    delegate?.didUpdatePosition(userPosition)
}
```

On the MapViewController side, you only must implement the protocol and assign self to the delegate of PositionController.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    positionController.setPositionViaLocationData()
    positionController.delegate = self
    var userPosition = positionController.getPosition()
    setUserPositionMarkerOnMapAndShowMap(userPositionLatitude: userPosition.userLatitude, userPositionLongitude: userPosition.userLongitude)
}

extension MapViewController: PositionControllerDelegate {
  func didUpdatePosition(_ newPosition: Position) {
    //Do whatever you want with the position
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! Secondly, I get two errors:        Cannot override unowned(unsafe) property with weak property               AND Property 'delegate' with type 'PositionControllerDelegate?' (aka 'Optional<PositionControllerDelegate>') cannot override a property with type 'CLLocationManagerDelegate?' (aka 'Optional<CLLocationManagerDelegate>')                                                How would I go about fixing them?

Comment: The message about overriding the method is a side effect that you made `PositionController` a subclass of `CLLocationManager` rather than subclass of `NSObject`. If you fix that (and fix the method declaration of `didUpdatePosition` as I mentioned above), you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I know of two methods to access location information once `CLLocationManager.requestLocation()` has a value.

1. Call your functions in the delegate methods of your location manager.

   ```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       //call function when you get user location
   }

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
       //handle error
   }
   ```
2. Use [PromiseKit](https://github.com/PromiseKit/CoreLocation), which provides a Promise that only returns once the location manager updates. You have to have `CLLocationManager.promise()` to get a Promise that returns when the location manager updates its location.

If you plan to use a lot of asynchronous calls, I would go for PromiseKit, since it makes handling and running asynchronous functions sequentially really straightforward. However, getting to know how PromiseKit works takes some time so if you would only use it for this single use case, I would rather go for method 1.

Answer (score 0):

As Rob commented, one cannot wait for the `locationRequest` method to end.

Looking at the code the `MapViewController.setUserPositionMarkerOnMapAndShowMap` method should be called from the `PositionController .locationManager(didUpdateLocations)` method.

The problem doing so is that the `PositionController` doesn't know about `MapViewController`.

Some options:

1. Pass an instance of the `MapViewController` to the `PositionController`.
2. Leave out the `PositionController` controller altogether and implement the functionality ('didUpdateLocations') in the `MapViewController`.

PS: Not related to your question directly but maybe indicating some confusion, both `MapViewController` and `PositionController` declare the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol but only the `PositionController` is implementing it.